# How do I change variable to string in python

Tags: python, string, variables

***Here is a example code for my problem***

```
    import random 


    variable1 = "lorem ipsum"
    variable2 = "lorem ipsum"
    main = 0
    
    if variable1:
        main = "".join(random.sample(variable1,variable2))
    
    
    print(main)
```

Then i get a error like this, I know what's the problem but I don't know how to fix it...

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: This code does not throw that error. It throws a syntax error, because you are missing a colon on `if variable == True`, if you add that colon, no error is raised (because a `str` is **never `==` to `True`**. Please **always provide a [mcve]**

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation for sample in the random package:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

The second argument to the sample(population, k) must be a number that represents the length of the list to return.

You are supplying two strings, so the python interpreter doesn't understand what variable2 means in terms of a length, because it's a string.

Change variable2 to an integer number and your code should work fine (note below).

Also, this is probably just a misttype in the question, but you need a colon at the end of the if statement declaration.

You also don't need to check if variable1 == True. That will only be true when you set a bool to it.

You probably mean, if variable1 is not null (None), so that line can just be:

```
if variable1:
```

Comment: sorry , it was just an example code and didn't pay atention to the syntax and the variables, in the original code everything was afine but i didn't pay attention to the example code I gave there, but I still can't find how to change the main variable to  "".join(random.sample(variable1,variable2))

Comment: It's in my answer. variable2 needs to be an integer, not a string. The second argument to random.sample is a number, to set the length of the returned list.

Comment: @defy14 again, **you must provide a [mcve]**. And a clear problem specification.